# How can I resolve issue in eventReactive function where ignoreNULL parameter is not working?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm making a dashboard using rmarkdown, shiny and flexdashboard. I'm using an action button to update the charts and tables. For this I use the eventReactive function. So that the information is displayed on the first access, I am setting ignoreNULL = FALSE. Apparently it's not working because the graphics are displayed in white. Only when clicking on the action button are the graphs filled. As far as I know the parameter ignoreNULL = FALSE allows the information to be displayed. What can I be wrong? Below is the code snippet.

Inputs {.sidebar data-width=300}
========================================================== =====================================

```
pickerInput(
    inputId = "year",
    label = "Select year:",
    selected = max(base_amb$year),
    choices = unique(sort(base_amb$year,decreasing = TRUE)),
    options = list(
       size = 3)
)

base_year <- reactive({

   base_amb[base_ambient$year == input$year,]
  
})

renderUI({

   pickerInput(
         inputId = "months",
         label = "Check/Uncheck the months:",
         choices = unique(sort(base_year()$month)),
         selected = unique(base_year()$month),
         # selected = c('01','02'),
         options = pickerOptions(
           actionsBox = TRUE,
           size = 10,
           selectedTextFormat = "count > 2"
         ),
         multiple = TRUE
       )
   
})

renderUI({
  
   pickerInput(
         inputId = "spec",
         label = "Check/Uncheck specialties:",
         choices = sort(unique(sort(base_year()$specialty))),
         selected = unique(base_year()$specialty),
         #selected = c("CARDIOLOGY","INFECTOLOGY"),
         options = pickerOptions(
           actionsBox = TRUE,
           size = 10,
           selectedTextFormat = "count > 2"
         ),
         multiple = TRUE
       )
    
})

actionButton(
   inputId = "apply",
   label = "Run",
   icon = icon(name = "play", lib = "font-awesome")
)

# reset button
actionButton(inputId = "reset",
              label = "Reset",
              icon = icon("sync"),
              width = '50%')

hr()
```

```
data <- eventReactive(eventExpr = input$apply, valueExpr = # When button is clicked...
                        { # ...this is executed
  req(input$year, input$months, input$spec)
  base_amb %>%
      filter(year == input$year) %>%
      filter(month %in% input$months) %>%
      filter(specialty %in% input$spec)

  },ignore NULL = FALSE)
```

```
time_data <- eventReactive( eventExpr = input$apply, valueExpr = # When button is clicked...
                        { # ...this is executed
  req(input$year, input$months, input$spec)
  base_time %>%
      filter(ano_inicio_atendimento == input$ano) %>%
      filter(month_inicio_atendimento %in% input$months) %>%
      filter(specialty %in% input$spec)

  },ignore NULL = FALSE)
```

```
observeEvent(eventExpr = input$reset, # When button is clicked...
              handlerExpr = { # ...this is executed
               
                updatePickerInput(
                  session = session,
                  inputId = "year",
                  selected = max(base_amb$year)
                )
               
                # Update picker widget: Product Line
                updatePickerInput(
                  session = session,
                  inputId = "months",
                  selected = unique(base_year()$month))
               
                # Update picker widget: Customer
                updatePickerInput(
                  session = session,
                  inputId = "spec",
                  selected = unique(base_year()$specialty))
               
                 # Delay and Mimic click on Apply button
                shinyjs::delay(ms = 300, expr = {
                shinyjs::click(id = "apply")
               })
 
  })
```

I hope some help from colleagues to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need your full markdown and your source data.  Also, pleasetranlate the final sentence of your question to English.

Comment: On a brief perusal of your code, I suspect most, if not all, of your `eventReactive`s should be `reactive`s.

Comment: I need them to respond to the actionButton to update the data. Only the first time it should be displayed without clicking the button.

Comment: Simply put a reference to the button inside your `reactive`s.  That will ensure they react to the button press.  Try it.  It works.  But, once again, without a minimal reproducible example - which includes *all* of the minimal amount of code necesseary to reproduce your issue *and* some test data - you reduce the chance of getting the help you want: potential helpers will answer those questions for which the necessary information has been provided rather than devote effort to trying to fugure out the information they should have received from you, but did not.